# How can I perform a parse and edit function on an article when it's saved?

Tags: django

For a Django blog, I'm trying to find a way to parse the content of an article and automatically make edits when certain conditionals are met, then save the article to the db once the function is complete.

Alternatively, I could do this from the view, but I figure it's more efficient and possibly easier to code if it's handled this way.

1. What do I need to edit so I can pass this function when an article is saved?
2. How can I parse the contents of the article and make changes when a conditional is met? Would something like the following work (pseudocode):

```
for line in object.content:
    line = line.rstrip()
    conditional:
        line = 'new line'
    object.content.save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could overwrite the save method of the model.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    
    ...
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Enter your parsing code here before the save
        # access the object with self.content instead of object.content
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        # anything done after the super will be post save
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods